# How can I get coordinates of a React-Native Maps Marker component through React Ref?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, coordinates, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

Please advice me how can I get the latitude and longitude values of a React-Native Marker component accross the React Ref object?
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md

in the React constructor:

```
this.markerRef = React.createRef();
```

in the Render method:

```
<Marker     
  ref={this.markerRef}
  coordinate={ ...some init coordinate... }
  draggable
/>
```

And what I want, is to get the Markers location infos, but NOT in the Marker's event handler(!)

```
onPressMarker(e) {
  const markerLoc=e.nativeEvent.coordinate
}
```

I know i can access the coordinates in the onPress event handler method, but I'd like to get the location data in an other class method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `draggable Marker`, its initial coordinates could update. In this case, you should store the coordinates in a `state` and update them on drag via the `onDragEnd` function. This behaviour is documented in the documentation.

Here is a minimal example.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {coordinate: someInitialCoordinate};
}

<Marker draggable
    coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
    onDragEnd={(e) => this.setState({ coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate })}
/>
```

Thus, on each coordinate change, the state will be updated. You can access them everywhere in your component.